# Node, Express, Dot env error in production (Heroku)

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, production-environment, dotenv

I am in trouble while deploying MERN app in **Heroku**. The application works properly in the local machine but in production, it gives me an error again and again.

> Starting process with command `node Shoping-Backend/server.js`
> /app/node_modules/path-to-regexp/index.js:63
> path = ('^' + path + (strict ? '' : path[path.length - 1] === '/' ? '?' : '/?'))
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

there is no `length` use in my app.js and server.js. I have already declared all **ENV** on Heroku's site. but still this error

versions

- node v14.17.4
- express@4.17.2
- dotenv@14.2.0

Procfile
`web: node Shoping-Backend/server.js`

my app.js file

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// const dotenv = require('dotenv'); 
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const errorMiddleware = require('./middlewares/errors/errors');

// setting up config files  // if this then why giving me error
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'PRODUCTION') require('dotenv').config({ path: 'shoping-backend/config/config.env' }); 


app.use(express.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(fileUpload());



const bassurl = process.env.BASS_URL // api/v1


// emport routes 
const product = require('./route/product');
const userRoute = require('./route/auth');
const orderRoute = require('./route/order');
const paymentRoute = require('./route/payment');


// middlewares 
app.use(morgan('dev'));
// app.use(cors());
app.use(cors({
     origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
     credentials: true,
     // allowedHeaders: 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
}));
// app.set('trust proxy', 1);

// endpoints 
// app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
//      res.status(200).json({message:'ok find it!!!'})
// });
app.use(bassurl, product);
app.use(bassurl, userRoute);
app.use(bassurl, orderRoute);
app.use(`${bassurl}/payment`, paymentRoute)


// add front static files
// if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PRODUCTION') {
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../shoping_front/build')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
     res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../shoping_front/build/index.html'))
})
// }

// error middlewares
app.use(errorMiddleware)

module.exports = app;
```

my server.js file

```js
const app = require('./app');
const connectToDatabase = require('./config/database');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');

// handle Uncaught exceptions Error (undefind verialbe or values)
process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
     console.log(`ERROR NAME: ${err.name} -> ERROR: ${err.stack}`);
     console.log('Shutting down the server due to Uncaught exceptions (undefind verialbe)');
     process.exit(1);
});
// setting up config files // if this then why giving me error
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'PRODUCTION') require('dotenv').config({ path: 'shoping-backend/config/config.env' });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Database conection
connectToDatabase();

// config cloudinary
cloudinary.config({
     cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
     api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
     api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
});

// listen
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
     console.log(`server started on PORT ${PORT} as ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode.`);
});

// handle unhandledRejection Error
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
     console.log(`ERROR NAME: ${err.name} -> ERROR: ${err.message}`);
     console.log('Shutting down the server due to Unhandled Promisse rejection');
     server.close(() => process.exit(1));
});
```

if I am already declaring all ENV then Why this error?

Comment: Please leave the emoji at home. They are almost never helpful, they just distract from what you are trying to ask. Focus on making your question as clear as possible. Nothing else.

Comment: `path.length` does not appear in your code. Please [edit] your question and show us the _full_ error message, with traceback. We need to know where it's coming from.

Comment: I am using the emojis just for attention on line ... Where is errors rises. This error become when I had removed DotEnv line from my application. There is no ```path.length```.

Answer (score 0):

Your Procfile definition has a route to the `server.js` file, you should use a route to `app.js` file instead.